# Class Based View, add data to the Form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm trying to achieve something that I tought would be pretty basic, but can't seem to find the solution for it.

I'm creating a pretty generic view for creating and updating users in a django app. I have a 'provider' model with associated permissions. I would like to add rights management in a very checkboxy simple way. When I show the form the checkbox should be check if user have permissions to add / delete / modify, and on the other hand, when the checkbox is checked, the permissions should be set in the database.

It goes like this :

```
class UserUpdate(UpdateView):
    form_class = UserForm
    model = User

    def get_initial(self):
        user = self.get_object()
        if user is not None and user.has_perm('core.add_provider'):
            return { 'right_provider' : True }

    def form_valid(self, form):
    user = form.save(commit=False)

    if form.right_provider:
        user.user_permissions.add('core.add_provider', 'core.change_provider', 'core.delete_provider')
    else:
        user.user_permissions.remove('core.add_provider', 'core.change_provider', 'core.delete_provider')
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

Then a form :

```
class UserForm(ModelForm):

    right_provider = BooleanField(label='Right Provider', required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name']
```

Apparently it's not the way to do it, since **'UserForm' object has no attribute 'right_provider'**

Am i doing it right, and if so, what is the issue with this code?
Is there litterature on how to pass data back and forth between the ModelForm and the Model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the value from the form's `cleaned_data`.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    if form.cleaned_data['right_provider']:
        ...
    else:
        ...
    return super().form_valid(form)

def form_valid(self, form):
    if form.cleaned_data['right_provider']:
        ...
    else:
        ...
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

Note I have removed the `save()` call - the form will be saved automatically when you call `super()`.

If you do need to call save in your view, I would avoid calling `super()`. I think it's clearer, and it avoids a potential problem of `save_m2m` not being called. See the docs for the [save method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) form more information.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    user = form.save(commit=False)
    ...
    user.save()  # save the user to the db
    form.save_m2m()  # required if the form has m2m fields
    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Another option is to call `super()` first without returning, then access `self.object`, and finally return the response.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    response = super().form_valid(form)
    user = self.object
    if form.cleaned_data['right_provider']:
        ...
    else:
        ...
    return response
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer, it works, but how am i supposed to get the user object without the form.save()? Also, how am i supposed to ensure that the user information is actually ok before adding or removing permissions?

Comment: You could get the user with `user = self.object` - it won't have the updated details yet, but since all your doing is adding/removing permissions, that shouldn't matter. If you call save with `commit=False`, then you might have problems if you have many-to-many fields in your form but didn't call `save_m2m`. You don't have any many-to-many fields in your case, but I didn't want future readers to be caught out.

Comment: As form your second question, you know that the information is actually ok because you are in the `form_valid` method. If the form data was invalid, then the view would call `form_invalid` instead.

Comment: I'll still have to find a way to manage the same thing on the creation view, since at this point the object does not exist...

Comment: For the create view, you can either call `save()` in the `form_valid` method yourself, or call `super()` at the beginning of the method. I've added examples of both of these above. My main point is that I think that calling `form.save()` and then `super()` is confusing, and might lead to bugs in certain circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Model forms expect the form fields to match the model fields. So you could add it as a field to your model.

If you only want the field on the form, you want to add it in the **innit** method of the form.

```
class UserFrom(ModelForm)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs)
        super(UserForm, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        # probably some code here to work out the initial state of the checkbox, 
        self.fields['right_provider'] = forms.BooleanField(label='Right Provider', required=False)
```